# Difference between sudo rm -rf and rm -vf?

Tags: command-line, sudo, rm

Recently I have seen one issue with a cache problem. The problem comes with broken hash and that could be fixed with

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf
```

But I am not understanding the difference between these two. Can somebody explain the difference?

Comment: As noted in the answers, these are 3 separate arguments, `r`, `v`, and `f`.  But not noted in the answers is that they can also be combined in different ways: `-rv` (what I usually use) and `-rvf` when you need all three.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

from the man Page:

> -r, -R, --recursive

remove directories and their contents recursively i.e. Folders inside them will be removed also.

> -v, --verbose

explain what is being done or show what is happening.

For the `-f`

> -f, --force           ignore nonexistent files, never prompt

You will not be promoted whether to remove the file or not. In other words: You will not be asked this question "Do you want to remove the files? Yes or No"

Answer (score 3):

-rf:

- The -r argument stands for "recursive." It will remove what you ask, as well as all files and directories underneath it.
- The -f argument stands for "force." It will ignore nonexistent files and never prompt.

-vf:

- The -f again stands for "force."
- The -v argument stands for "verbose." It will print all items it deletes.

The biggest difference is this: -rf will remove all files and directories under the location you asked for, and print nothing. -vf will NOT remove non-empty directories and print everything it does delete.

Note that this information comes from the man page:

```
$ man rm
```